# How to change font size in multiple html textareas using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is confusing me. I'm trying to get this javascript to change the font size of multiple textarea's with id=label. Problem is, on the first jsfiddle it is only changing the first textarea, and when i try it on a jsfiddle with more of my code included if fails to work at all!!!! Any advice would be great.

```
$("#fontsize").change(function() {
    $('#label').css('font-size', $(this).val() + 'px');
}).change();
```

Here is a simple jsfiddle that seems to work on the first textarea- https://jsfiddle.net/q7jz9034/2/

And here it is intergated with a bit more of my code and css, making it stop working all together!! - https://jsfiddle.net/m4pdjywx/

Comment: An id is supposed to be unique in the page. You should rather use a class to access the elements.

Comment: IDs are, by definition, unique. Your HTML is invalid for that reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot have more elements with the same id - that's the purpose of ID. Your solution is to change `id` to `class` (for example,  `<textarea class='label'>` ) and change your javascript to `$('.label')`.

Edit:
Here is your updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4pdjywx/4/). You already had class on `textarea` elements, so I just updated that part. However, your code was not subscribing to `change` event, rather emiting it so I updated that part too:
`("#fontsize").on('change', function() { ... }`

You also didn't include jQuery in that fiddle and I also added wrapper to wait for jQuery to load: `$(function(){ // ... }`

As you can see, everything is working as expected now :)

Comment: Just a comment, you can have more than one element with the same ID, but you shouldn't. You could access them all using `$('[id=label]')`. It's slower and NOT recommended at all, but you could.

Comment: well, technically yes, you can, since the website with multiple IDs renders but as you say this solution would be slower and the HTML is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Just another point. **You shouldn't use id if you have several items you want to change.** *Instead you can use tag name*. Please follow my example:

```
$("#fontsize").change(function() {
    $('textarea').css('font-size', $(this).val() + 'px');
}).change();
```